# how to update selected radio button in flutter using getx statemanagment

Tags: flutter, state-management, flutter-getx

I am using Flutter with GetX plugin and I have two radio buttons inside statelessWidget
but the radio button doesn't changed to selected when user click on it
my question is how I can update screen to show selected radio the groupValue attribute changed using GetX pluing.
here is my code

```
Radio(
  value: reportController.period[0],
  groupValue: reportController.selectedPeriod,
  onChanged: (val) {
                     reportController.selectedPeriod = val;
                              
                    },
     )
```

and this is my controller

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'package:ycom/models/report.dart';

class ReportController extends GetxController {
  var report = Report().obs;
  List<String> period = ["evening", "morning"];

  void set selectedPeriod(String selectedPeriod) {
    report.update((report) {
      report.selectedPeriod = selectedPeriod;
    });
  }

  String get selectedPeriod => report.value.selectedPeriod;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by wrapping Radio widget inside Obx() function as following

```
Obx(() => Radio(
                 value: reportController.period[0],
                 groupValue: reportController.selectedPeriod,
                 onChanged: (val) {
                                   reportController.selectedPeriod = val;


                                },
               ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to achieve this:

My Controller:

```
      class ProfilePageController extends GetxController {
      String selectedGender;
      final List<String> gender = ["Male", "Female"];

      String select;
      void onClickRadioButton(value) {
      print(value);
      select = value;
      update();
      }
     }
```

My View Code:

```
          Row addRadioButton(int btnIndex, String title) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        GetBuilder<ProfilePageController>(
          builder: (_) => Radio(
              activeColor: Colors.blue,
              value: profilePageController.gender[btnIndex],
              groupValue: profilePageController.select,
              onChanged: (value) =>
                  profilePageController.onClickRadioButton(value)),
        ),
        Text(title)
      ],
    );
  }
```

To use, call addRadioButton:

```
          Row(
            children: [
              addRadioButton(0, "Male"),
              addRadioButton(1, "Female"),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score -5):

Try `{setState(() {reportController.selectedPeriod = val;});}` instead `{reportController.selectedPeriod = val;},`

Comment: setState doesn't work in statelessWidget I am using getX plugin for statemanagment

Comment: its hard by this documentation https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Radio-class.html you need use setState to update view of Radio. You can change way to set or get data because you cant update view in Statelessmanager read this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html

Comment: GetX plugin can do this because it manage the state and you can use it instead of stateful widget and update widgets 
I just don't know what is the code or method can deal with string values

Comment: use sharedpreference https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value

Comment: the solution should use getx not a random bunch of technologies